# display data with number of week count in table and appending data form database php mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, for-loop

I am finding trouble displaying my data in table using for loop in php.

I am using bootstrap as my front-end and php mysql as my backend.

I have really tried to display data as the first image but I get image 2 result over and over.

Even if I try styling it with css the table's column and row do not appear as shown in the first image
Here is the image [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTvCC.png)[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cTMF.png)
[This is what i want the table to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epKph.png)

[but i ama getting this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWQvt.png)

expected result should be [this is the expected outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPEmf.png)
Below is my code

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<?php
  $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','reservations');
  $startingDay = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("first sunday of this month -6 days"));
  $numberOfDays = 35;
  $dates = array();
  $weekCounter = 1;
  $meetingRow  = '';

  for ($i = 0; $i <= $numberOfDays - 1; $i++) {

    $date    = date('m/j/Y', strtotime("$startingDay +$i days"));
    $dates[] = $date;

    if (date('l', strtotime($date)) == "Monday") {

      $meetingRow   .= '<div class="container">';
      $meetingRow   .= '<table class="table" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">';
      $meetingRow   .= '<tbody>';
      $meetingRow   .= '<tr><td colspan="8"></td></tr>';
      $meetingRow   .= '<tr>';
      $meetingRow   .= '<th>Week ' .  $weekCounter++ . '</th>';

    }

    $meetingRow    .= '<th>';
    $meetingRow    .= '<p>' . $date. '</p>';
    $meetingRow    .= '<p>' . date('l', strtotime($date)). '</p>';
    $meetingRow    .= '</th>';

    if (date('l', strtotime($date)) == "Sunday") { 

        $meeting_room_sql = "
    SELECT id
         , meeting_room_name 
      FROM meeting_room
    ";
        $meeting_room_result = mysqli_query($con, $meeting_room_sql);
        // you are to use $meeting_room_result not $meeting_room_sql error occurs in fetching from meeting_room
        while ($meeting_room_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($meeting_room_result)) {

            $meeting_room_id    = $meeting_room_row['id'];
            $meeting_room_name  = $meeting_room_row['meeting_room_name'];

            $meetingRow   .= '<tr>';
            $meetingRow   .= '<td>';
            $meetingRow   .= '<div>' . htmlentities($meeting_room_name, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8") . '</div>';
            $meetingRow   .= '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#meetingModal">Reserve</button>';
            $meetingRow   .= '</td>';

            $reserved_sql = "SELECT meeting_room_id, reserved_date FROM meeting";
            $reserved_result = mysqli_query($con, $reserved_sql);
            while ($reserved_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($reserved_result)) {

                $reserved_room_id = $reserved_row['meeting_room_id'];
                $reserved_date    = $reserved_row['reserved_date'];

                if ($reserved_room_id == $meeting_room_id) {
                    $meetingRow   .= '<td>' . htmlentities('Meeting Reserved ' . date('m/j/Y', strtotime($reserved_date)), ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"). '</td>';
                } else {
                    $meetingRow   .= '<td><br /></td>'; 
                }

            }
        }

        $meetingRow   .= '<td><br /></td>'; 
        $meetingRow   .= '<td><br /></td>';             
        $meetingRow   .= '<td><br /></td>'; 
        $meetingRow   .= '<td><br /></td>'; 
        $meetingRow   .= '<td><br /></td>'; 
        $meetingRow   .= '</tr>';
    }

    $meetingRow   .= '</tbody></tr>';
    $meetingRow   .= '</table>';
    $meetingRow   .= '</div>';
  }
  echo $meetingRow;
?>
<script>
    $(function() {
      $("#meeting_date").datepicker();
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
{
"meeting_room": {
    "Room 1": {
        "id":1,
        "meeting_room_name":"meeting room 1"
    },
    "Room 2": {
        "id":2,
        "meeting_room_name":"meeting room 2"
    },
    "Room 3": {
        "id":3,
        "meeting_room_name":"meeting room 3"
    },
},
"meeting": {
    "1": {
        "id":1,
        "meeting_room_id":"2",
        "reserved_date":"02/02/2019"
    },
    "2": {
        "id":2,
        "meeting_room_id":"02/03/2019",
    },
    "3": {
        "id":3,
        "meeting_room_id":"01/31/2019",
    }
}
}
```

Comment: have you tried inspecting the code in the browser and see?

Comment: yes i have tried

Comment: are the empty table cells are coming ? it yes then I guess you just have to add CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, There are many issues with your logic here, First you are creating new table each time its `Monday` so the first thing is to move the starting and ending tags of table out of the loop.

Now I don't have the databases but I hope it will fix the issue.

```php
<!-- language: lang-php -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','test');
$startingDay = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("first sunday of this month -6 days"));
$numberOfDays = 35;
$dates = array();
$weekCounter = 1;
$meetingRow  = '';
$meetingRow   .= '<div class="container">';
$meetingRow   .= '<table class="table" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">';
$meetingRow   .= '<tbody>';




for ($i = 0; $i <= $numberOfDays - 1; $i++) {

    $date    = date('m/j/Y', strtotime("$startingDay +$i days"));
    $dates[] = $date;

    if (date('l', strtotime($date)) == "Monday") {

        $meetingRow   .= '<tr><td colspan="8"></td></tr>';
        $meetingRow   .= '<tr>';
        $meetingRow   .= '<th>Week ' .  $weekCounter++ . '</th>';
    }

    $meetingRow    .= '<th>';
    $meetingRow    .= '<p>' . $date. '</p>';
    $meetingRow    .= '<p>' . date('l', strtotime($date)). '</p>';
    $meetingRow    .= '</th>';

    if (date('l', strtotime($date)) == "Sunday") {

        $meeting_room_sql = "SELECT id , meeting_room_name  FROM meeting_room";
        $meeting_room_result = mysqli_query($con, $meeting_room_sql);
        // you are to use $meeting_room_result not $meeting_room_sql error occurs in fetching from meeting_room
        while ($meeting_room_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($meeting_room_result)) {

            $meeting_room_id    = $meeting_room_row['id'];
            $meeting_room_name  = $meeting_room_row['meeting_room_name'];

            $meetingRow   .= '<tr> 
                                 <td> 
                                    <div>' . htmlentities($meeting_room_name, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8") . '</div>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#meetingModal">Reserve</button>
                                 </td>';

            $reserved_sql = "SELECT meeting_room_id, reserved_date FROM meeting WHERE meeting_room_id = {$meeting_room_row["id"]}";
            $reserved_result = mysqli_query($con, $reserved_sql);
            $total_number_of_rows = 7;//As we have 7 days in a week so we have 7 days column

            $RowCounter = 0;
            while ($reserved_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($reserved_result)) {
                $RowCounter++;
                $reserved_room_id = $reserved_row['meeting_room_id'];
                $reserved_date    = $reserved_row['reserved_date'];

                if ($reserved_room_id == $meeting_room_id) {
                    $meetingRow   .= '<td>' . htmlentities('Meeting Reserved ' . date('m/j/Y', strtotime($reserved_date)), ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"). '</td>';
                } else {
                    $meetingRow   .= '<td><br /></td>';
                }
            }
            while ($RowCounter < $total_number_of_rows){
                    $meetingRow   .= '<td><br /></td>';
                    $RowCounter++;
            }

            $meetingRow   .= '<tr>';

        }
        $meetingRow   .= '</tr>';
    }



}
$meetingRow   .= '</tbody>';
$meetingRow   .= '</table>';
$meetingRow   .= '</div>';
echo $meetingRow;
?>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#meeting_date").datepicker();
    });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Update** Now the above code is working fine but the logic for getting meetings is not correct you should get meeting by that specific date.  Let's say if same day have two meetings than you need to add the data in same column.

[image]

Comment: thank you sir but still got a problem in displaying the dates of reserved rooms on my table tried the if logic but seams not to work

Comment: Can you post the data of your both queries as JSON?

Comment: i have appended the json data

Comment: Give me a minute.

Comment: still having the same problem i want the date displayed to be similar with the one on the header (th) if week one  date 2/2/2019 the reserved date fetched should be displayed on that column which is 02/02/2019

Comment: That's what i mentioned that you have to change your query! will update it.

Comment: please help still cannot figure it out